# How to set a SELECT value equal to a different column if the original column is NULL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

```
SELECT TOP 10
        VendorId,
        CASE WHEN VendorNumber IS NULL THEN VendorId
        END AS 'VendorNumber'
FROM    Table
```

The above does not work.

Basically I want to do this:

I want to select 2 columns: VendorId and VendorNumber.

If the VendorNumber IS NULL, I want to display the VendorId.

How can I accomplish this with the query above? The query is basically showing NULLs instead of the VendorID.

Comment: Why you want to display vendorid column twice?

Comment: In your code you need **ELSE**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify an `ELSE`, or you will get null when `VendorNumber` is *not* null:

```
SELECT TOP 10
        VendorId,
        CASE WHEN VendorNumber IS NULL THEN VendorId ELSE VendorNumber
        END AS 'VendorNumber'
FROM    Table
```

You can simplify by using [`isnull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [`coalesce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
select top 10 VendorId, isnull(VendorNumber, VendorId) as VendorNumber
from Table
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `ELSE` so it is placing a `null` in all rows where `VendorNumber` is not null:

```
SELECT TOP 10 VendorId,
    CASE 
        WHEN VendorNumber IS NULL 
        THEN VendorId
        ELSE VendorNumber
    END AS 'VendorNumber'
FROM    Table
```

This can also be written as:

```
SELECT TOP 10 VendorId,
    Coalesce(VendorNumber, VendorId) AS 'VendorNumber'
FROM    Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
Select top 10
            VendorId,
             COALESCE(VendorNumber, VendorId) as vendornumber
From table

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select top 10, vendorid, coalesce(VendorNumber,VendorID) VendorNumber
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL function to do this is `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT TOP 10 VendorId, coalesce(VendorNumber, VendorId) as VendorNumber
FROM    Table
```

This assumes that VendorId and VendorNumber are the same type.  Otherwise, you may need to add in some conversions.  For instance, if VendorId were a character string and VendorNumber a number:

```
select top 10, VendorId, coalesce(cast(VendorNumber as varchar(255)), VendorId)
from Table
```

Answer (score 0):

"Else" is missing.

```
 SELECT TOP 10 VendorId,
        CASE 
            WHEN VendorNumber IS NULL 
            THEN VendorId
            ELSE VendorNumber
        END AS 'VendorNumber'
    FROM    Table
```